# How to root Tecno Camon 12 air?

Tags: rooting, root-access

I want to root my Tecno Camon 12 Air but nothing works. I got samsung devices rooted within a blink but this one just does not. I have:

- Allow OEM bootloader to be unlocked checked
- Tried different PC softwares like KingoRoot iRoot etc.
- Tried almost all of the apps which said they could root

I have searched everywhere and tried almost everything but could not have the job done. Every time some adb command is rejected by an indefinite  printed on the command-line or it just reboots to get back normal. No change. Nor the fastboot commandos work as in fastboot it gets hang on the same  thing. Which is a crucial step in ROM patching or bootloader unlocking.

Its running Android 9 Pie and the processor is MTK Helio P22 if that helps.

Comment: your device is most likely Mediatek MT6762 Helio P22 chipset, search for [similar](https://forum.xda-developers.com/showpost.php?p=81395595&postcount=278) devices and learn from their root methods. a common method is boot image [patching](https://www.thecustomdroid.com/install-magisk-root-android-devices/#Method-2-By-Flashing-Magisk-Patched-Boot-Image-using-Fastboot)

Comment: @alecxs already searched and viewed the link

Comment: so your problem is actually how to enter fastboot with Volume Down + Power or adb reboot-bootloader? it would be helpful to post exact output of error messages

Comment: No no I can enter fastboot.... Just that no command actually work in fastboot and no response on device is observed. There ain't any message either but prompt is also gone

Comment: install latest [platform-tools](https://www.xda-developers.com/google-releases-separate-adb-and-fastboot-binary-downloads) and [drivers](https://developer.android.com/studio/run/win-usb) (while connected in fastboot mode)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So I was able to root Tecno Camon 12 Air. Turned out the biggest hurdle was to unlock bootloader which can be unlocked as follows:

### Unlocking Bootloader

Use this command: `fastboot getvar unlocked` to check the phone’s Bootloader status (whether it’s locked or unlocked). If the Bootloader is already unlocked then you should see “Unlocked”

If locked you need to run the following command:

```
fastboot flashing unlock
```

And then reboot:

```
fastboot reboot
```

Alternative commands are `fastboot oem unlock` and `fastboot oem unlock-go`